# Ps4 controller randomly stops working

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

My PS4 and controller I bought 7 months ago have been fine until yesterday. The PS4 did a system update, and after that I downloaded and installed Fallout 4 from the disk. This is when the problem started.

Within 5 minutes of playing, my controller just stopped working. The light remained on and there was no error message, no internet disconnection, and no matter what button I pressed on the PS4 there was no response. I read online troubleshooting suggestions and half the time, if I reset my controller, it will work for a short time then back to no response. The other half of the time it remains unresponsive. The only time it seems to always work is when my PS4 is off and I use the PlayStation button to power on PS4.

Any suggestions to get back to playing?

Comment: Maybe your controller just has a faulty battery